# How can i add request and response to socketIO

Tags: node.js, socket.io

The problem is that I want to use req.session in socketIO event.
how can i put it into the funtion.
At first:

```
io.on("connection",function(socket){

});
```

what I want is

```
io.on("connection",function(req,res,socket){
   console.log(req.session.user);
});
```

is it possible?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass session middleware in socket request and response and then you can use session in socket

```
const sessionMiddleware = session({
    name: 'SESSION_ID',
    secret: '$%@#$ASSee',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 86400000
    }
});
app.use(sessionMiddleware);
io.use(function (socket, next) {
    sessionMiddleware(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
console.log(socket.request.session.userId);
 })
```